# Windows UEFI repair

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, multi-boot, uefi, efi

I have an Acer Aspire 571-series laptop that came with Windows 8 preinstalled (now upgraded to 8.1). Last week I installed the OS X Yosemite (hackintosh) to triple boot with Windows and Ubuntu, and all was working well until yesterday. When exploring the OS X system I modified what I shouldn't have modified: The EFI Partition. Now I can't boot into Windows, and the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> Acer access to the recovery partition isn't working. I know that Windows is still installed because I can see the main partition and the recovery partition from Ubuntu, so I have also access to the WinRe.wim and all the recovery files, but I don't know how to make a bootable USB with them.

I'm also considering other options, like reinstalling Windows 8 (I don't know how the license key works in this case), or repairing the EFI partition from Linux.

How can I do these things? What is the best way to fix my system?

Comment: You can create a W8.1 installation media from this Microsoft website ==> http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media Your license key is in the BIOS and should work automatically.

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad I could help.